# OCR rotated image

Tags: algorithm, ocr

I have a couple of images including labels that have angles between 0 and 180 degrees. Is there any way to detect them using existing OCR tools or any algorithm for that?

Comment: Is the entire image rotated the same way, or does the image contain multiple labels where each label is rotated differently?

Comment: Each label rotated differently.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago i wrote such algorithm for this:

- cut one letter
- rotate it clockwise from -X degress to X degres from initial posiotion, stepping by 1-2 degrees
- With each rotation catch it to a block, by checking most outside pixels in every side
- With each rotation check/remember dimensions of a block
- After all rotations find a block that have highest height/width ratio and rotate initial letter to that position
- You have now properly rotated letter, but pay attension, that wide letters will lies on side (like W, will be rotated 90 degrees) so you have to create pattern for W for comparsion on its side, not normal

Comment: Hi. Interesting approach, but fails when it's a font where e.g. "n" or "o" are quadratic. Do you know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), an open-source OCR now developped by Google will have an orientation detection feature in version 3.0. The code is included in the svn version, but I don't know if it works.